# Hypothesis testing for two samples from discrete distributions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, discrete-distributions

There exists a classical method for solving a certain computational problem related to random sampling. It is the "gold standard", so to speak.

I'm working on an algorithm that aims to solve the same problem more efficiently. It relies on partitioning the data used in the classical method and processing it in parallel.

For my algorithm to work, I need statistics (count of occurrences of elements of each type) related to these partitions of the data.

I believe I modeled these statistics correctly using a certain classical discrete distribution, but I note it is a problem of sampling without replacement. So, while I have fixed parameters for the first partition's distribution, the parameters of the second partition depend on the actual statistics of the first partition and not just their distribution. Similarly for the third, fourth, etc. partitions.

Thus, there is actually a family of parameters for each partition, except for the first, which as I mentioned, is fixed.

By running the classical algorithm millions of times, I collected many samples for the statistics of each partition. I also collected statistics of the same type by running my proposed algorithm millions of times.

Plotting histograms of the samples from both algorithms shows essentially identical distributions, which increases my confidence that my modeling was correct. However, I'd like to upgrade from visual inspection to an actual hypothesis test that these two sample sets come from the same distribution. Given that the classical algorithm is the gold standard, if a test does not reject the null hypothesis of both sample sets coming from the same distribution, then I would have evidence of my modeling being correct.

However, due to the issue explained above, of there being a family of parameters for all partitions except for the first, I only have a pmf formula for the first partition -- my limited knowledge of statistics is insufficient to obtain pmfs for the remaining partitions which mix together samples from distributions of different parameters.

Thus, I'm looking for a good hypothesis test to run my data through. I tried the [chi-square test using the SciPy Python package](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chisquare.html), but I've run into the problem that the "expected" frequencies cannot be zero, yet I do not actually have expected frequencies per se, but rather observed frequencies from the "gold standard" method. I have reason to believe they are likely to remain zero at the tail-ends even if I were to collect statistics from a months-long run of the algorithm.

Looking at SciPy's document, I've found other tests apparently applicable to my scenario, except that most of them mention continuous rather than discrete distributions: [Kolmogorov-Smirnov 2-sample test](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ks_2samp.html), [Cramér-von Mises 2-sample test](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.cramervonmises_2samp.html). The only one that explicitly mentions discrete distributions is the [Anderson-Darling k-sample test](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.anderson_ksamp.html), so unless I learn something new, it's the one I'll probably use.

I now have a bunch of questions in an attempt to find the "best" test:

- Can I "fix" the chi-square test given that some of the "expected" frequencies at the tail-ends are and will remain zero?
- Is the Anderson-Darling k-sample test a good fit for my problem?
- Do the other mentioned tests such as Kolmogorov-Smirnov and Cramér-von Mises work only for continuous distributions, or could I apply them to my (discrete) case?
- Out of all the "workable" options (currently Anderson-Darling only), which is more indicated?

Comment: All the tests you mention rely on independent observations but your observations are dependent. Rather than ask about issues with your attempt to solve the problem (none of which work for your situation), ask instead about how to solve the problem you started with.

Comment: @Glen_b I'm not sure I follow. Do you mean that I should ask what tests are applicable to the situation of validating whether samples from two ("unknown" in a sense) distributions are the same? Or that I should describe my problem, the modeling I've done, and whether that modeling is correct?

Comment: it would help to understand enough about the structure of the data to allow concrete discussion of the test you're trying to do. It **sounds** like you have a multivariate hypergeometric response, but maybe there's some aspect of the problem I have missed.

Comment: You are correct that a multivariate hypergeometric distribution is involved. I'd rather not go into too much detail, so I ask: is that enough information to make some recommendations about hypothesis tests?

Comment: Someone may be prepared to hazard an answer based on what's there.